# Pop3 to SMTP message custom forwarder in C#

Tags: c#, smtp, pop3, forwarding

I'd like to write a service that periodically checks a POP3 account for new messages and based on custom business logic forwards the messages to an appropriate "To", and possibly changes the "From" as well.  I might need to keep some messages on the server until certain conditions are ready for them to be forwarded.

I found a sample using Chilkat .NET components that might work:
http://www.example-code.com/csharp/pop3_forwarder.asp

My question is:  Are there any other examples of this in the .NET space using any other components?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following SO questions/answers might help finding components for the POP3 part of your porject:

- [Reading Email using Pop3 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c#102135)
- [Free POP3 .NET library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606/free-pop3-net-library)

And you can use [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) in *System.Net.Mail* for sending the mails:

- [Sending E-mail using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449887/sending-e-mail-using-c)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I found Peter Huber's "POP3 Email Client with full MIME Support" at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Pop3MimeClient.aspx and it looks like it will work well.  It has an easy api, and it downloads each message from a POP3 server as a "System.Net.Mail.MailMessage".

Comment: ...then I can modify the message according to my needs and then forward the MailMessage on using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something very similar using MailBee's [IMAP](http://www.afterlogic.com/products/net-imap-component), [POP](http://www.afterlogic.com/products/net-pop3-component) and [SMTP](http://www.afterlogic.com/products/net-smtp-component) .NET components.

They're not free, I'm afraid, but I've found them to be pretty solid, and AfterLogic's support is fast.

There's also the free (including source code) [LumiSoft Mail Server](http://www.lumisoft.ee/lswww/ENG/Products/Mail_Server/mail_index_eng.aspx?type=info), that has POP3 relay support to collect messages from a POP3 server and manage them from there, you could adapt that? (It's written in C#, is nice to work with and upgrades cleanly to VS2008). I've had no problems with that either.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Mail.dll .NET email component](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/). It has SSL support, POP3 and SMTP clients.

```
using(Pop3 pop3 = new Pop3())
{
    pop3.Connect("mail.host.com");    // Connect to the server 
    pop3.Login("user", "password");

    foreach(string uid in pop3.GetAll())
    {
        // Receive mail
        IMail mail = new MailBuilder()
   .CreateFromEml(pop3.GetMessageByUID(uid));
        Console.WriteLine(mail.Subject);
    }
    pop3.Close(true); 
}
```

You can [download it here](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/)