# Auto Response for a mail in C#.NET

Tags: asp.net

I need to know how to create an auto-responder email for a mail which we received from a user. For example if a user sending a mail to us, he should receive a mail as an acknowledgement from us.

Please suggest some ideas for how to perform this task by using c# codebehind.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you tell us how the email is being read/processed/stored what servers/software etc then this is too broad a question and will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple implementation of POP3 you can receive and filter emails. There are many POP3 implementations on the Net. [Please check this out](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14304/POP3-Email-Client-NET-2-0). With something like this you can simply listen for incoming messages at all times and filter when an email was received from a specific user. [In this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656881/pop3-to-smtp-message-custom-forwarder-in-c-sharp) you can also find how to send emails using POP3 or SMTP for auto-replying your emails.

Good luck!