# Email handling in C#

Tags: c#, .net, email

I need to know the object name for handling emails in C#/.NET Framework.

Answer (score 6):

You need the namespace System.Net.Mail.

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx) is an example from the ScottGu's blog.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("sender@foo.bar.com"); 

message.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient1@foo.bar.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient2@foo.bar.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient3@foo.bar.com")); 

message.CC.Add(new MailAddress("carboncopy@foo.bar.com"));
message.Subject = "This is my subject";
message.Body = "This is the content";


SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 3):

[System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) is the namespace to look in.  Start with [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) or [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Ekeko's answer if you would like to use an external mail server you must specify the host in the SmtpClient constructor.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.yourmailserver.com");
```

And you might also need authentication to be specified if your server requires it.

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers are assuming that you are asking about SMTP handling.  POP3 is not handled natively in the .NET framework.  You will have to purchase a third-party library.  I'd recommend the Ostrosoft POP3 library.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of questions in stack Overflow that describes how you can send.

- [Sending E-mail using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449887/sending-e-mail-using-c)
- [send email c#](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=send%20email%20c%23&page=2&tab=relevance)