# Sending emails on separate threads using QueueUserWorkItem

Tags: c#, multithreading, smtp

I have a console application that sends customized emails (with attachments) to different recipients and I want to send them concurrently. I need to create separate SmtpClients to achieve this so I am using QueueUserWorkItem to create the emails and send them in separate threads.

**Snippet**

```
var events = new Dictionary<Guid, AutoResetEvent>();
foreach (...)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
    {
        var id = Guid.NewGuid();
        events.Add(id, new AutoResetEvent(false));
        var alert = // create custom class which internally creates SmtpClient & Mail Message
        alert.Send();
        events[id].Set();
    });   
}
// wait for all emails to signal
WaitHandle.WaitAll(events.Values.ToArray());
```

I have noticed (intermittently) that sometimes not all the emails arrive in the specific mailboxes with the above code. I would have thought that using `Send` over `SendAsync` would mean the email has definitely sent from the application. However, adding the following line of code after the `WaitHandle.WaitAll` line:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Seems to work. My thinking is, for whatever reason, some emails still haven't been sent (even after the `Send` method has run). Giving those extra 5 seconds seems to give the application enough time to finish.

Is this perhaps an issue with the way I am waiting on the emails to send? Or is this an issue with the actual Send method? Has the email definitely been sent from the app once we pass this line?

Any thoughts idea's on this would be great, can't quite seem to put my finger on the actual cause.

**Update**

As requested here is the SMTP code:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("Host");
FieldInfo transport = client.GetType().GetField("transport", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
FieldInfo authModules = transport.GetValue(client).GetType()
    .GetField("authenticationModules", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
Array modulesArray = authModules.GetValue(transport.GetValue(client)) as Array;
modulesArray.SetValue(modulesArray.GetValue(2), 0);
modulesArray.SetValue(modulesArray.GetValue(2), 1);
modulesArray.SetValue(modulesArray.GetValue(2), 3);
try
{
    // create mail message
    ...
    emailClient.Send(emailAlert);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // log exception
}
finally
{
    emailAlert.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Can you create a short, but complete, program that exhibits the problem?

Comment: @Lasse I will try the suggested solutions then post if still nothing.

Comment: Why can't you use `SendAsync` and just process the completion events so you know if all of the emails have been sent?

Comment: I think you missed some of the code. I don't see any call to send.

Comment: @Brian I want to send the alerts ASAP and they can be triggered pretty much 1 after the other, you are only allowed to send 1 asychronously at any 1 time, that was my original idea.

Comment: @Kiquenet you don't seriously expect me to post my full application code do you? Surely the code posted in my question & the answers below is enough for you to go on?

Comment: Not full application, only sending email process if it's possible like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1687178/206730 I would like compare samples, for find more clear, more elegant code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the things that's bugging me about your code is that you call `events.Add` within the thread method.  The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class is not thread-safe; this code should not be inside the thread.

**Update:** I think ChaosPandion posted a good implementation, but I would make it even simpler, make it so nothing can *possibly* go wrong in terms of thread-safety:

```
var events = new List<AutoResetEvent>();
foreach (...)
{
    var evt = new AutoResetEvent();
    events.Add(evt);
    var alert = CreateAlert(...);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
    {           
        alert.Send();
        evt.Set();
    });
}
// wait for all emails to signal
WaitHandle.WaitAll(events.ToArray());
```

I've eliminated the dictionary completely here, and all of the `AutoResetEvent` instances are created in the same thread that later performs a `WaitAll`.  If this code doesn't work, then it must be a problem with the e-mail itself; either the server is dropping messages (how many are you sending?) or you're trying to share something non-thread-safe between `Alert` instances (possibly a singleton or something declared statically).

Comment: But surely every thread is being signalled ok otherwise my application would wait forever?

Comment: Not if the `WaitAll` happens before all the threads have even had a chance to add their event to the dictionary.  That's why it's important to initialize the list in the same thread that you wait in.

Comment: Ah very good point! I think will may have hit the nail on the head though.

Comment: Have you tried the updated version?  I have a feeling that the dictionary access may have been part of the issue, it isn't thread-safe.  Construct the list of events in the foreground thread, do away with the dictionary completely, and you should be fine.

Comment: Spot on, that seemed to solve the issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: A genius use of closures, one thing you could do is shorten `delegate` to `o =>`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to do this...

```
var events = new Dictionary<Guid, AutoResetEvent>();
foreach (...)
{
    var id = Guid.NewGuid();
    events.Add(id, new AutoResetEvent(false));
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
    {           
        // Send Email
        events[(Guid)state].Set();
    }, id);   
}
// wait for all emails to signal
WaitHandle.WaitAll(events.Values.ToArray());
```

Comment: or  `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>{     events[(Guid)state].Set();}, id);`

Comment: I did this so I don't have to ask if he has .NET 3.5.

Comment: For the record I do have 3.5, just trying your solution at the mo will get back to you guys!

Comment: Hmm, the var should have been a red flag for me. I need a vacation.

Comment: Same result, 1 email this time didn't arrive in the mailbox (i waited a little extra for it) then adding the thread sleep worked!

Comment: Break it down for me, `Worked` or `Didn't Work`.

Comment: Actually, your version is probably a bit better than mine, but if you're going to pass the id as state, why not pass the `AutoResetEvent` instead?  That would eliminate the potentially non-threadsafe dictionary lookup.  Or better yet, don't pass state at all; store the `AutoResetEvent` in a local variable before adding it to the dictionary, and just put `event.Set()` in the delegate.  The more I look at it, the more the dictionary seems unnecessary, you could do this just as well with a `List`.

Comment: Since the look up is read only we can assume it is thread safe. I think the problem is that the program ends too quickly and kills the sending of the emails.

Comment: @Chaos, that is the issue, I am trying to stop this from happening!

Answer (score 2):

The reason why its not working is that when he hits events.Values.ToArray() *not all of the queued delegates have executed* and therefore *not all AutoResetEvent instances have been added to the dictionary*.

When you call ToArray() on the Values property, you get only those ARE instances already added!

This means you'll be waiting for only a few of the emails to be sent synchronously before the blocked thread continues.  The rest of the emails have yet to be processed by the ThreadPool threads.

There is a better way, but <strike>this is a hack</strike> it seems pointless to do something asynchronously when you want to block the calling thread in the end...

```
var doneLol = new AutoResetEvent();

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
delegate
{
  foreach (...)
  {
    var id = Guid.NewGuid();
    var alert = HurrDurr.CreateAlert(...);
    alert.Send();
  }
  doneLol.Set();
});   

doneLol.WaitOne();
```

---

Okay, considering the following requirements:

1. Console App
2. Lots of emails
3. Sent as fast as possible

I'd create the following application:

Load the emails from a text file (File.ReadAllLines).  Next, create 2*(# of CPU cores) Threads.  Determine the number of lines to be processed per thread; i.e., divide the number of lines (addy per line) by number of threads, rounding up.  Next, set each thread the task of going through its list of addresses (use Skip(int).Take(int) to divvy up the lines) and Send()ing each email synchronously.  Each thread would create and use its own SmtpClient.  As each Thread completes, it increments an int stored in a shared location.  When that int equals the number of threads, I know all threads have completed.  The main console thread will continuously check this number for equality and Sleep() for a set length of time before checking it again.

This sounds a bit kludgy, but it will work.  You can tweak the number of threads to get the best throughput for an individual machine, and then extrapolate from that to determine the proper number of threads.  There are definitely more elegant ways to block the console thread until complete, but none as simple.

Comment: Of course this only uses one thread for all the alerts... they are still being sent sequentially instead of in parallel.  If the objective is just to do it in the background then that'll work fine, but if he's trying to send them all in parallel then this doesn't do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I know, its just about pointless.  Why do this asynchronously when you want to block?

Comment: I assumed that it was in order to improve overall throughput.  `Send()` might take a relatively long time to execute, but if the mail server accepts 10 connections at the same time then the parallel version will finish much faster.

Comment: I want the alerts to go ASAP and I just want the application to wait for ALL alerts to have been sent. If the application ends too quickly then some alerts don't get sent hence why I need to wait.

Comment: Well, if `alert.Send()` blocks until sent (you'll have to create a demo project to test this), then just send them synchronously.  If you want to prevent application shutdown from stopping them from getting sent, create a new Thread and use it to run your alerts (i.e., don't use a "background" thread; see here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0.aspx )

Comment: @Will...that is what I HAVE been doing, look at my original post. I am sending the emails in separate threads.

Comment: @Will: That's exactly it.  The `Send` method probably blocks for a second or two, but most of that time is idle, it's just sending data across the wire and/or waiting for a response from a mail server.  Sending them in parallel will improve the throughput (I assume).

Comment: Honestly, I'd just skip the multithreading as your requirements don't seem to call for that.  If you end up with a metric s*tton of emails the ThreadPool will not be much more efficient than running it synchronously (depending on # of cores and what else is going on with the box).

Comment: Alternatively, you can create X number of threads (maybe 2x CPU cores) and split up the emails among them.  I'd probably do this using a ConcurrentQueue<T> holding Actions which each thread then executes...

Comment: @Will at the moment there won't really be many emails going, however, in the future I do expect quite a number. I will defintely look into the ConcurrentQueue<T> solution thanks.

Comment: That's a 4.0 collection, btw.

Comment: Ah I am on 3.5, is there anything I could look at in this version?

Comment: Hmmm... It originated in the Parallel Fx library, but that never had a go-live license.  You might want to look at Jeffrey Richter's (i.e., Wintellect) Power Threading library.  I believe it has some concurrent collections.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (using SmtpClient from a thread and the emails arrive only intermittently).

Initially the class that sends emails created a single instance of SmtpClient. The problem was solved by changing the code to create a new instance of SmtpClient everytime an email needs to be sent **and** disposing of the SmtpClient (with a using statement).

```
 SmtpClient smtpClient = InitSMTPClient();
 using (smtpClient)
 {
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    ...
    smtpClient.Send(mail);
 }
```