# how to send mail using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

i want to send mail to any email address, how to do that using C#. i am working on local host.

Comment: Ppsslbe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449887/sending-e-mail-using-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message=new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(
                new MailAddress(EmailUsername), new MailAddress("toemailaddress"));

message.Subject = "Message Subject";   // E.g: My New Email
message.Body = "Message Body";         // E.g: This is my new email ... Kind Regards, Me
```

For the SMTP part, you can also use `SmtpClient`:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(ServerIP);
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(EmailUsername, EmailPassword);
client.Send(message);
```

Please consider accepting some answers. A 0% accepted rate is not great.

---

Edited to fix the silly mistakes. Serves me right for not checking the code first.

Comment: `System.Web.Mail` has been deprecated.

Comment: The `To` property is a collection, and `From` is not a string.

Comment: I suggest an improvement just `SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()` and then use of web.config for configuration `<mailSettings> <smtp from="me@my.net"> <network host="myhost.com" password="if needed" userName="if neede"/> </smtp> </mailSettings>`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class and call [Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.send.aspx) (or [SendAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendasync.aspx)) with a [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) instance. Both these classes are in the [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) namespace.

SmtpClient's [default constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1c4h6e2.aspx) uses the [configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164240.aspx) from your app/web.config, but you can use [other constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.smtpclient.aspx) to specify the SMTP settings you want.

```
// using System.Net.Mail;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

MailMessage mm = new MailMessage()
{
    Subject = "Subject here",
    Body = "Body here"
};

mm.To.Add("email@tempuri.org");
mm.From = new MailMessage("from@tempuri.org");

client.Send(mm);
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the stuff-ups in my answer. Sorted them now.

Answer (score 2):

just to add that, there is a really nice website with **everything you should know about** System.Net:Mail namespace

it is called:

> [http://www.SystemNetMail.com/](http://www.systemnetmail.com/)

hope it helps someone like it's been helping me ever since :)

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for the plug. I always appreciate coming across other developers who enjoyed my site.  Thanks! Dave.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.Net MVC I would recommend that you have a look at [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
public static void Send(string pFrom, string pSubject, string pTo, string pBody)
{
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage loMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    System.Net.NetworkCredential loCredencial = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(MAIL_USERNAME, MAIL_PASSWORD);
    loMail.To.Add(pTo);
    loMail.Subject = pSubject;
    loMail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(pFrom);
    loMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    loMail.Body = pBody;
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient loSmtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(MAIL_SMTP);
    loSmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    loSmtp.Credentials = loCredencial;
    loSmtp.Port = MAIL_PORT;
    loSmtp.Send(loMail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to send Email with Attachment

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

public void email_send()
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("your mail@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("to_mail@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
    mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("c:/textfile.txt");
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your mail@gmail.com", "your password");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
  private static void SendMail(string subject, string content)
    {
        try

        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("YOURMAİL");
            mail.To.Add("MAİLTO");
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = content;
            SmtpServer.Port = 25;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("YOURMAİL", "YOURMAİLPASSWORD");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

And don't forget to add ---using System.Net.Mail;---