# how to send mail in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

hii
 i  m trying to send mail through coding of asp

is there any external APIs to send mail like JAVA

give some hints 
if possible sample code!!

I m using vs 2005 as well as vs 2008

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354436/how-to-send-mail-using-c

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class. Example using GMail's SMTP:

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("youraccount@gmail.com", "secret");

var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("youraccount@gmail.com");
mail.To.Add("youraccount@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Test mail";
mail.Body = "test body";
client.Send(mail);
```

---

UPDATE:
Example with yahoo:

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587);
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("youraccount@yahoo.com", "secret");

var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("youraccount@yahoo.com");
mail.To.Add("destaccount@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Test mail";
mail.Body = "test body";
client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: @program-java, yes `mail.To`is the receiver and `mail.From` is the sender. In my example I've used the same account for testing purposes.

Comment: okay   thanks...
if i want to use yahoo  instead of gmail then what ill be the Smtp?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.Web.Mail;
private void SendMessage()
```

{

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

mail.To = txtTo.Text;

mail.From = txtFrom.Text;

mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;

mail.Body = txtBody.Text;

SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";

SmtpMail.Send(mail);
```

}

if want to send attachment

Add the following code

```
mail.Attachments.Add(new MailAttachment(@"C:\myFile.txt"));
```

Comment: SmtpMail is obsolete. You should use SmtpClient - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx