# Forgot password - I miss something

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, dotnetnuke

I have made custom login control for dotnenuke. Now I am trying to implement forgot password feature but I miss something I can get password by username but can't find how to send mail to user.

```
 UserInfo ui= UserController.GetUserByName(this.PortalId, "JohnDoe");

            string pass = UserController.GetPassword(ref ui, "");
```

Comment: What have you been searching for? There are plenty of questions about sending e-mail from c# here on Stack Overflow alone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to send mail using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354436/how-to-send-mail-using-c)

Comment: I thought that DotNetNuke have some method that I can call to send that email for me?

Comment: So change your question to 'How to send an email from DotNetNuke?'. 'I miss something' is not a good question to ask.

Comment: Are you using the Membership Provider? If so it has functionality built in for resetting passwords. Looking at your code there seems to imply that either your password are stored as encrypted strings or - and this is the scary option - that you're holding them as clear text. Otherwise you're not going to be able to retrieve the password from the database anyway. Please tell me you're not holding them as clear text.

Comment: Adding to @Ira Rainey's comment; please do not send the plain text password in an email to the user. :( It is very insecure, and you run the risk of your website / application being hacked.

Comment: @Jason and @Ira, by default, DNN encrypts passwords (rather than hashing).  Definitely not clear text, but not super awesome either.

Comment: @bdukes Great; thanks for the info. The snippet makes it look like @1110 is trying to send the password via email which would then be in plain text. But judging by your answer, it looks like DNN has password reminder functionality built in. Definitely better.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail` class.  Depending on what you want, you may just need to call `Mail.SendMail(user, MessageType.PasswordReminder, portalSettings)`