# form data email

Tags: c#, asp.net

How would I send e-mail to any specified e-mail address in asp.net C#.

Comment: possible duplicate -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449887/sending-e-mail-using-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to start by looking into the [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) namespace. If you're talking about sending emails beyond your own servers, though, keep in mind that [sending email through code may not be as simple as it seems.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) ;)