# regarding email firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2000

i m new to web developement. i want to send email to the user if some answers has been added to his question. you can think of the notify option in stack overflow website or like what happens in a forum. i want the logic behind. how to start..

Comment: have you tried searching first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending E-mail using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449887/sending-e-mail-using-c)

Answer (score 0):

The classes you're looking for are in the System.Net.Mail namespace.  Check out this link:

[It's from 2.0 but still valid in 3.5 /4.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx)