# How to send a detailed email to specific developer from Azure DevOps on failure of unit tests from a Build pipeline?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to send a detailed email containing information about all failed unit tests in a pipeline and said email must be sent to the developer who wrote the unit tests.

Currently, I have a Visual Studio Test task in my build pipeline which executes my tests and sends an email on failure which provides at least *some* information.

However:
a) I would like the email to be be send to the developer who wrote the tests.
b) Email should contains all the details of the tests that failed (such as can be seen in the "Tests" tab of a completed build).
[The automatic email does not provide all the details I want and mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flkdu.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Devops does not support that feature. You may add your request here: 
[Azure DevOps (formerly Visual Studio Team Services)](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-azure-devops-formerly-visual-studio-team-services).

As workaround and if you have coding experience, you can try to analyze test runs with Rest Api ([Results - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)) and send email ([Sending E-mail using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449887/sending-e-mail-using-c-sharp)).

Comment: As a quick clarification for @Touqeer - Azure DevOps does not support exporting tests results and reports, but you _can_ send customized emails if you want to. So the feature you'd like to request is to have access to the test report as file dump.

Comment: I got it. I appreciate your response, now officially I come to the point that there is no such thing for which I was looking for. So I don't need to spend more for searching for this solution.

Comment: yeah; just give up. Much better :)