# How to use API request Result-Get in Azure automated pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rest-api

I'm trying to send a detailed email-notification on test failure in azure pipeline build. I'm following the suggestion in this thread : [How to send a detailed email to specific developer from Azure DevOps on failure of unit tests from a Build pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55509785/how-to-send-a-detailed-email-to-specific-developer-from-azure-devops-on-failure)
I saw the example request as below

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}?api-version=5.0
```

How can i get the value of 'runId' and 'testCaseResultId' ? Is there any environment variable that can use in my pipeline to automatically substitute their values ?

Can anyone suggest me a best way to use [Result-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)?

Comment: Hi SruthiChedath，Just checking to see if the information provided was helpful.  If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for marking it as an answer, which will also help others in the community.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT sorry, i didn't get time to check it . Thank you for your respone and i'll check that solution when my current task is done. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get a test result for a test run by using [this Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). Both `runId`  and `testCaseResultId` Parameter are required.

However, you are trying to fetch it during a build/release pipeline. This API is not apply to your situation. Since the build is still running not completed. So you need to **get it through build/release task log**.

[Releases - Get Task Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20task%20log?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

We used to use the following API to **get test results** for the release,
`GET https://{instance}/{project}/_apis/ResultDetailsByRelease?releaseId={RELEASE.RELEASEID}&releaseEnvId={RELEASE.ENVIRONMENTURID}`

The test results included testRun ID or get failed tests only by **using filter**,
`GET https://{instance}/{project}/_apis/ResultDetailsByRelease?releaseId={RELEASE.RELEASEID}&releaseEnvId=RELEASE.ENVIRONMENTURID}&%24filter=Outcome+eq+Failed`

Similar with build --[Timeline - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#taskresult)